# A Issue related to DataBinding with TextBlock

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, databound

I have a class where have some `get;set;` properties. And `OnPropertyChange` event, have calculated additions of all those `get;set;` properties. 
There are other properties that just have `get;` and it returns a calcuation simple like:

```
public Double D_F_Percent { 
    get {
        return d_f / total;
    }           
}
```

These properties are bound to TextBlocks. Initally, the values show up as *NaN*. But later when I enter values for `d_f`, and it gets added up to toal in `OnPropertyChanged`.

Now my point is after calculating total how do I call this property and fire it so it gets refreshed in the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire the `PropertyChanged` anytime and the binding engine will update the UI.

It's not required to do it in a property setter. So in the method where you calculate `total` just raise the event with your calculated property name `D_F_Percent`.

See in the sample  `CalculateTotal` method:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double d_f;
    public double D_F
    {
        get { return d_f; }
        set { d_f = value; FirePropertyChanged("D_F"); }
    }

    private double total;
    public double Total
    {
        get { return total; }
        set { total = value; FirePropertyChanged("Total"); }
    }

    public Double D_F_Percent
    {
        get { return d_f / total; }
    }

    public void CalculateTotal()
    {
        //Do some calculation set total
        FirePropertyChanged("D_F_Percent");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nemesv, it does the job perfectly well. Just I have used OnPropertyChanged everywhere in place of FirePropertyChanged. I hope that should be fine - I mean not a bad idea. BTW, what will FirePropertyChange do in cntrast to OnPropertyChanged ? I had to add an if() and call CalculateTotal() in my PropertyChanged event.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call your event raiser method, `OnPropertyChanged` is also a good name it just a matter of personal preference.